# How to secure config file while hosting a web service on a public domain

Tags: security, iis, web-hosting

I currently have a web service which I would like to host publicly but my company policy is against exposing the `web.config` file outside of our company firewall. Is there a way where I can host my web service on a public server securely?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to how IIS works, your `web.config` file won't be accessible from outside your application. You won't be able to get to it by just browsing directly to it unless you manually allow that action such as enabling directory browsing etc.

The `web.config` file is more an IIS config than anything else, as it merely configured the IIS environment to run the application as you intend it to.

You have nothing to worry about